# difference between blunt and brusque

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

I cannot tell the fine differences between the synonyms *brusque* and *blunt*.

```
Blunt suggests lack of polish and of regard for the feelings of others.
Brusque connotes sharpness and abruptness of speech or manner.
```

However, the definition of *blunt* also includes "abrupt in address or manner". Does this mean that *brusque* is simply a more precise adjective that carries a subset of the meaning of *blunt*?

Comment: I've always viewed "blunt" as meaning direct and not inclined to "sugar coat" anything.  Whereas "brusque" to me implies being dismissive and not taking the time to, eg, explain why a decision was made.

Comment: Second Hot Lick's comment: to me at least, 'brusque' also suggests brief, whereas 'blunt' can be any length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being rude comes to mind when I hear *brusque* and rude may be sharp, and pointed. Blunt is defined by its dullness.

It goes to intent, like objective and subjective are different. Blunt may simply be facts, while brusque involves an implied shortness, or impatience.

Answer (score 2):

*He spoke **brusquely/bluntly***.

***Brusquely*** describes how you deliver your comment (abruptly, tersely, briskly, peremptorily, offhandedly, rudely ...(OED))

*antonym* - politely, verbosely (Google)

***Bluntly*** describes the character of your comment (without ceremony or delicacy; abrupt, curt, to the point, frank, candid, direct, bluff, undiplomatic, indelicate, ...(OED))

*antonym* - subtly, tactfully (Google)